# Guid in Querystring is being transformed somehow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, firewall

I am not sure why this is occuring but here are a few details that may help to find a solution:

- It seems to work correctly on most computers firefox and IE
- It occurs to certain Guids as others work
- We put the firewall in monitor mode and still occurs

This is the line in PageModify.aspx building the query string:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("Editor.aspx?id={0}", pageId,
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

This is the output of the query string when all goes correctly:

```
https://example.com/Editor.aspx?id=1dfz342b-3a4d-4255-8054-93916324afs6
```

This is what is viewed in the browser when redirected to Editor.aspx:

```
https://example.com/Editor.aspx?id=1dfz342b-3a4d-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx324afs6
```

Of course we get an invalid guid error when this line runs:

```
_PageEditId= new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

Has anyone seen this? Could it be IIS settings? Nothing special is being done here and everyone's systems has the same baseline. It occurs to inside and outside customers.

Comment: Is `pageId` actually typed as a `Guid`?

Comment: Looks like the kind of behavior that you would get with a monitor for personal information.  Does it only happen when the GUID components are numeric?  Maybe it thinks that is a SSN or phone number and is blanking it out for privacy.

Comment: Mark Peters - Bing, it was a default firewall setting masking what appeared to be a credit card number. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom. You should answer your own question and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

A [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) is a [`Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx), so you have to parse it when it comes through the querystring as a `String`:

```
Guid PageEditId = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]); //add null checks or use TryParse
```

Comment: @rick: The `Guid` constructor will attempt to parse any string that you pass it. There's no need to call `Parse` explicitly.

Comment: @tom Why you didnt check this answer ?

Answer (score -1):

I think `-` is not valid character for query string value, encode it:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("Editor.aspx?id={0}", Server.UrlEncode(pageId),
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Comment: I can go to the page and edit as it should but several people can't and a server error is thrown. All with the same Guid as the Id.